# Passing char* buffer to C# as a StringBuilder

Tags: c#, c++-cli, marshalling, stringbuilder, c-strings

I have a C++ function that is called with a char* buffer to be used for the output. Now i want to write to it using C# so i need to call a managed method from the C++ function. What i can't figure out is how to pass it as a StringBuilder.

I previously used [Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) which worked fine and did this automatically using a default string marshalling scheme, but i want to use the size parameter for the MaxCapacity of the StringBuilder.

Is there a nicer way to do this than creating a new StringBuilder instance, writing to it, getting a CLR string with `ToString()`, and then copying the contents to the buffer? The strings in question might be as long as 10,000 characters and i don't really like the idea of copying it twice each time.

**C#**

```
public static void MyMethod(StringBuilder buffer)
{
    //...
}
```

**C++/CLI**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void __stdcall MyFunction(char* buffer, int length)
{
    MyNamespace::MyClass::MyMethod( /* ? */ );
}
```

Comment: You'd have to copy it *anyway*, since .NET strings are made of 16-bit wide chars, and your function uses the 8-bit `char`. You *have* to convert it to 8-bit at some point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `byte []` then c++ 8 bit character array will align correctly.
2. I prefer to do something similar to this because I use it for unmanaged code:

   ```
   String ^ ToManagedString(const char * pString) {

   return Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr((char *)pString)); // Marshal pString into Managed Memory. return as a C# string reference (^).

   }


   const std::string ToStdString(String ^ strString) {
       IntPtr ptrString = IntPtr::Zero;
       std::string strStdString;
       try {
           ptrString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(strString);     // Marshal a C# String reference into unmanaged HEAP memory space.
           strStdString = (char *)ptrString.ToPointer();            // Convert C# IntPtr to char* implicitly, call assignment operator of std::string to copy.
         }
         finally {
             if (ptrString != IntPtr::Zero) {
                  Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptrString);
              }
         }
        return strStdString; // return std::string copied out of interop unmanaged heap space
   }
   ```